# Java equivalent of JavaScript Timeout functions

Tags: java, javascript

I am translating some Javascript code into Java, and need to know how to do Timeouts in Java. How would I translate the following into Java?

```
var x = setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 2000);
clearTimeout(x);
```

Comment: You will have to use Timer thread for this type of work.

Comment: Maybe this? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Launch a new `Thread`. In case you need a delay in the execution, you can use `sleep()`

Anyway it is basically different, in JS you do not have a 'Main thread' (JS is run by the browser threads) while in Java you have it. So, if what you want to do is to call a function separately at specified times, you create just one thread and in this thread you make a loop with sleep and your logic (and mark the thread as daemon).

Comment: Is there a significant performance hit from creating a new thread? I only want to set a variable after 500 ms, seems a bit overkill to spawn a new thread, but I am ok with it if there is no performance issue.

Comment: I believe usually it is not light, but it depends of the environment, in J2EE usually there is a pool so most of times you don't create them but reuse some, in J2SE I am not sure (I believe there are not such pools). Also, it is not the same if you are in the main thread (and thus `wait` freezes the GUI) or in a secondary thread. And of course, how many times you do that. Also, different OS / VM implementations may mean different penalties for creating a thread.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I think I will change my code pattern to work around this issue, from your answer, it seems like Java timers are not appropriate for small tasks if they can avoided.

Answer (score 4):

Try out with java.util.Timer

You can schedule your task when the specified time is over or into a periodic interval. Use

> myTimer.schedule(tt, 2000);

where tt is a TimerTask object from java.util.TimerTask (you have to implement the run() method, who will correspond to your "function(){ ... }" in javascript).

Comment: scheduleAtFixedRate for periodic tasks

Comment: does this create a new thread? and is there an equivalent way to cancel as with js `clearTimeout()`?

Comment: Yes it does. You can cancel it with cancel() method from Timer class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a thread and paste your business logic (in which you want to wait). Then use `Thread.sleep(2000);`. However it is depending on your needs that what exactly you want to do with your java code. Also you can use `public interface Lock` like this :

```
 Lock lock = ...;
  if ( lock.tryLock(50L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ) ...
```